# Antd DatePicker setValue form Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I was trying to set a form Date Value for DatePicker using

```
this.prop.form.setValue
```

it sets but when i try to change the date and submit it shows the same set date it doesn't change the date.

> Using antd DatePicker

#### have tried it on this link  (Do change the antd version to 3.16 as some features are deprecated in the new antd releases )

https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-waterfall-3fhkt?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around it apperently antd saves the value into ._d and not into the main key value

> the below code solved it for me

```
moment(values.dtReading._d).format()
```